# How can I make changes in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, faq-proposed

I have been here for 3 months. So far, my username is a rather generic user123456-type name and my avatar is some coloured geometric shape. However, I can’t help noticing that many others have a unique name and/or picture.

I would like to change mine too, but I can't find the place where to do it. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Click on your username. You will be brought to your user page. Then click on "Edit Profile and Settings" or similar. You can modify stuff there.

Comment: I can reach to my profile,but further i m unable to do anything.(when i click on my photo it again takes me to my activities.

Comment: Go to this URL: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/34347/vidyanshu-mishra and click on "Edit Profile & Settings". You'd be able to change your profile image there by clicking on "change picture" which is below your account picture.

Comment: OK, I see you have succeeded. :) One thing though, you can change your profile pic any time, but you can only change usernames once every month.

Comment: @rubisco thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

To do that, you need to first access your profile. You can do that in a number of ways:

- In the top bar, you can see your avatar next to your current reputation and your badge count. That is a link to your profile.
- Anywhere on the site where you can see your name — under answers, questions or on the question page — your username is also a link to your profile.

You need to do this from the [main site](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com) (i.e. *not* from meta) to be able to advance to the following step.

Once there, note the bold, blue text reading *Activity*. This is your personal greeting-page when you access your profile. Next to activity are two links, one named *Profile* (this is what everybody else sees when they access your profile) and the other named *Edit Profile & Settings*. (If you’re still on meta it will just read *Settings.* Click on the small *main user* icon to its right.)

You will now access the editing page as can be seen below. From here on it is self-explanatory: make the corresponding changes and save.

[image: edit profile]

Actually, there is one further thing. You are given *two* options of saving. One will apply the changes to *all* your Stack Exchange profiles. The other will apply them *only* to Chemistry (and Chemistry Meta). Choose wisely.

Finally, note that every time you change your username, you cannot re-change it for 30 days (except for a 15 minute grace period at the beginning). [Meta.SE source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180)

Comment: @Rubisco Can you give me a source for only being able to edit the username once a month? If so, I’ll gladly include it.

Comment: Rubisco is dead. :( There you go. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names